# including another file after #!/usr/bin/php -q

Tags: php, email

I cannot seem to include ANY other file outside of the current directory once i use `#!/usr/bin/php -q`.

If I echo get_include_path() after using the above its showing me `.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php`

So I guess the question is, how do I include the file that I have highlighted in red in the image below.

Since this is an email piping script I am working on, If I send and email to that email, I get a reply back with error. That error is also attached here.

[image]
[image: error]

Comment: What error message does it give you?

Comment: It's most likely a rights issue, since they're in different user directories. You'll need to make sure that `americanimg` has read rights to `imgimportsinc`'s file.

Comment: You are correct. But how do I make sure americanimg has read rights into imgimportsinc?